# Transposing and summing the top 5 results in Teradata SQL Assistant

Tags: sql, sum, teradata, transpose

I have a query that I converted from Access and is currently working correctly in Teradata SQL Assistant. The data pulled is just a standard table full of all of the data I need.

What I am wondering is: Can something be added to this query that will essentially sum up all of the Exposure values and then only show the top 5 Divisions by greatest to smallest sum (of those Top 5). Also, transposing the data so that my Topics are the left most column.

Here is the working code, details omitted.

```
SELECT 
A.AS_OF_DT
, B.DIVISION
, B.CLASS
, Sum(A.BALANCE/1000000) AS "Bal in MMs"
, Sum(A.EXPOSURE/1000000) AS "Exp in MMs"
, Sum(CASE WHEN A.STATUS = 'NACC' THEN  (B.BALANCE/1000000) ELSE 0 END) AS "NPL Bal as MMs" 

FROM DB.TABLE1 A LEFT JOIN DB.TABLE2 B ON A.NAICS = B.NAICS_CD

WHERE A.AS_OF_DT= '2017-03-31'

GROUP BY 
    A.AS_OF_DT, 
    B.DIVISION, 
    B.CLASS 

ORDER BY SUM (A.EXPOSURE/1000000) DESC
```

Essentially I want the columns to be the following:

DIVISION|DATE|

Below DIVISION would only be the Top 5 DIVISIONS summarized by EXPOSURE (under DATE)

I can try and clarify if needed. Just let me know.

Thanks!

End result is to have a datapaste I can throw into Excel without the manual work of transposing the data in Excel along with writing formulas to rummage through the 1000's of results of the base query to find summarize the individual Divisions and then picking the top 5 each month.

Thanks!

Shill

Answer (score 1):

To get the 5 top for each division, you can use [QUALIFY](http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_111A/Ordered_Analytical_Functions.083.016.html).

Add this to the end of you query:

```
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY AS_OF_DATE,DIVISION order by (SUM (A.EXPOSURE/1000000))
```

For your other questions, SQL Assistant isn't much of a presentation tool, it won't do what you are asking for.

Comment: I'll give this a shot thanks. Unfortunately this is what I am stuck using.

Answer (score 0):

If your query already work,

try replacing:

```
SELECT
```

By:

```
SELECT top 10
```

(line 1)

Comment: Doesn't this just return the top 10 rows that would typically appear?

Comment: oh, yeah, i'm sorry, i didn't exactly understand what you where asking for

Comment: Essentially I am trying to sum up Exposure across all divisions, so where I have duplicate divisions, that exposure is just summed up to essentially turn say 1000 rows into 50 (50 separate divisions). Then I want to pull the top 5 based off Exposure (largest exposure to smallest, but only the top 5) Any way to do this?